# How to: Change the DataGrid IsSelected Background (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, background

**How to: Change the DataGrid IsSelected Background (C#, WPF)**

I do have the following code in my `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Unfortunately, the following result is what I get:
[image]

What do I need to do to fix my Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this bit of Xaml to your data grid resources...

```
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

The two brushes work together to set the background/foreground when a row is selected.

To set the default colours for a DataGrid row, you can add this snippet...

```
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This sets the background to Pink and the Foreground to DodgerBlue.

More info on the SystemColors static resource is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx

Comment: Okay, thanks. The first one is working - the second one is not working. However, I decided to use method one. Unfortunately, I need to change the foreground now. How can I do that?

Comment: @Exception Add an entry for SystemColors.ControlTextBrush and check your result

Comment: @Exception, added the default properties to the style that may fix why the second one did not work...

Comment: Okay, well I tried to fix my problem, but you sent a code for the mouse over effect and the general background. I just need the `IsSelected` property...

Comment: @Exception, just checking, did you see the comment about  SystemColors.ControlTextBrush ?

Comment: Yes, and that is working as well, but I need the `IsSelected` property. ;-)

Comment: @Exception, I'll look at this again.  Can you confirm your selection unit is row and selection mode is single?

Comment: Selection unit is row, yes. Selection mode is single, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the style for `IsSelected` property on `DataGridCell` as it is (apparently) rendered after `DataGridRow`.

Comment: Okay, but now I cannot see my text anymore. It is covered by the `WhiteSmoke` Background.

Comment: @Exception Then add new setter in the `IsSelected` trigger to change the cell `Foreground` color of your choice.